# Discord.py - Check if user has specific rule (if function)

Tags: python, discord.py

I've looked through other posts and I can't seem to find a solution for my problem.
I made a small if-function check for my kick command to see if the player you're trying to kick is not part of the staff.

The staff role is "Team".

```py
@client.command()
@has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def k(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    if discord.utils.get(ctx.server.roles, name="Team") in member.roles:
        await ctx.send('You cannot kick a staff member')
    else:
        await member.kick(reason=reason)
        await ctx.send(f'Kicked {member}. Reason: {reason}')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to test purely off of names:

```py
if "Team" in [r.name for r in member.roles]:
    # code
```

Or you can do it via ID, which would be recommended as it means you can change the name of the role in your server without having to update your code.

```py
if 112233445566778899 in [r.id for r in member.roles]:
    # code
```

To get the role ID:

- Make sure you have Developer mode enabled (Settings > Appearance > Scroll down > Enable Developer Mode)
- Direct yourself to your server's role list
- Right click on the staff's role > `Copy ID`

The reason that your code didn't work is that you wrote `ctx.server` instead of `ctx.guild`.
See [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html#server-is-now-guild) for more information.

---

**References:**

- [List comprehension in Python](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension)
- [Migrating from Async (v0.16.x) to Rewrite (v1.x)](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html#server-is-now-guild)
- [`Member.roles`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.roles)
- [`Role.id`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Role.id)
- [`Role.name`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Role.name)

Comment: I tried the ID method, but it did not work...
I even tried with `ctx.guild` previous times. When loading up the script, the CMD prompt simply closes with no error message left behind.

Comment: Sorry, I should've made it `in` instead of `not in`. Also, could you try running it in IDLE or another IDE? So then you can read the error.

Comment: I get an inconsistent usage of tabs and spaces error, maybe I can fix it

Comment: Glad to hear it! Good luck with the rest of your bot :^)